# How to get list of all classes coming with particular JDK from cli?

Tags: java

I found file `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/classlist` that consist of list of classes.

Why there is this file? It it is consist of list of classes that coming with this version of JDK, or only JRE?

Is there any file that contains list of all classes coming with JDK?

*Linux solution prefered*

Comment: AFAIR, JDK & JRE have actually the same runtime, so the classes availanble should be exactly the same... JDK only has additional compiler, tools, docs, src etc.

Comment: @vaxquis thanks for qualification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to find all the classes in a JDK is to examine all the jars

```
find $JAVA_HOME -name *.jar -print | xargs -n1 jar -tf
```